# Any way for template substitution to happen before argument dependent lookup (or workarounds?)

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup, cereal

I suppose the basic premise of this question is that I'm trying to use `enable_if` along with Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL), but I'm not sure if it's possible. I do see on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) that

> Template argument deduction takes place after the function template name lookup (which may involve argument-dependent lookup) and before template argument substitution (which may involve SFINAE) and overload resolution.

So I imagine this won't work, but in the spirit of learning I'd like to put the question out there.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to get to happen:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace lib1 {
  template <typename T>
  void archive(T & t)
  {
    serialize(t);
  }
}

namespace lib2 {
struct VectorInt {
  int x;
  int y;
};

struct VectorDouble {
  double x;
  double y;
};

template<typename T>
void serialize(std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, VectorInt>::value, T>::type & vect) {
  std::cout << vect.x << std::endl;
}

// maybe do something different with VectorDouble. Overloading would work,
// but I'm curious if it can be made to work with enable_if

}

int main() {
  lib2::VectorInt myvect;
  myvect.x = 2;
  lib1::archive(myvect);
}
```

The example is loosely based on something I'm trying to do with the cereal library. In my case I have several different types of vectors and matrices, and while I can use overloading to get functions to resolve properly, I was curious to use the `enable_if` feature to see if I could shorten the code.

Anyway, trying to compile that gives a message "error: variable or field 'serialize' declared void".

It's my understanding that this won't work because the `enable_if` is evaluated only after argument dependent lookup? Is that right?

For those that want to play around with this, I have the code up on repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/HalfBlandJumpthreading

Comment: `T` is not deducible or provided for `serialize`.

Comment: Do you want [that](https://repl.it/repls/MenacingPrudentTransversal) ?

Comment: What’s T in your main function? vector<int>? I guess in this case you need to change the signature?

Comment: Overload `void serialize(VectorInt& vect)` seems simpler.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld It's VectorInt, sorry, changed some code but not all!

Comment: @Jarod42 In this case yes, however my real use case is a little more complicated. I'd like to implement `serialize` the same way for a couple types that have the same member variables, but differently for other types. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @Jarod42 Re: your example: ... I guess so? I was having trouble with default arguments, but it seems to work with your example. However, I'm confused as to why it works with void* and not T in the place of the type for `enable_if`? I'm also confused as to why it works at all since the second template argument is not used?

Comment: You almost never want to use enable if that way. Pass by simple const T &, and use a defaulted second template parameter. Your problem has nothing to do with adl, as soon as you pass the VectorInt it's namespace gets searched and it works fine. The problem is that you have disabled template deduction by how you declare the parameter.

Comment: In fact Jarod42s link is already dead on, I suggest studying it and reading up a bit on when template parameter can and can't be deduced

Comment: @NirFriedman Thanks for the answer. If you could elaborate in a more broken-down ELI5 sort of way it would really help! I'm rather confused about how the defaulted second parameter works. I can see it working with Jarod42's code, but don't understand how/why.

Comment: I guess this is how SFINAE works? When it tries to evaluate that function template with VectorDouble, the substitution fails and the compiler is left trying to find `::type` inside the `enable_if` struct, but it doesn't exist because the condition was false, and so it just chalks it up as a substitution failure and moves on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two separate things going on in your example: there's (function) template argument deduction, and there's argument dependent lookup (ADL). The relationship between these two is slightly complex if you start trying to explicitly specify template parameters (hey, it's C++), you can read more here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl (in the notes section).

That said, in general in C++ it's typically better to allow function templates to deduce their arguments rather than specify them explicitly, which is what you were trying to do here anyway, so all is well.

When you do:

```
namespace lib1 {
  template <typename T>
  void archive(T & t)
  {
    serialize(t);
  }
}
```

The call to `serialize` qualifies for ADL, and since it depends on t it is deferred until the template is instantiated since the type of `t` is required (this is called 2 phase lookup). When you call `archive` with an object of type `VectorInt`, the call to `serialize` will look in the namespace of `VectorInt`. Everything is working just fine. The problem is in this code:

```
template<typename T>
void serialize(std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, VectorInt>::value, T>::type & vect) {
  std::cout << vect.x << std::endl;
}
```

You didn't specify template parameters explicitly, so they have to be deduced. But the form you give here does not allow deduction: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction, see non-deduced contexts, the very first example. To try to understand better why, consider what you are asking the compiler to do: you are passing a `VectorInt` and asking the compiler to find `T` such that `std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, VectorInt>::value, T>::type>` happens to be `VectorInt`. This seems reasonable because intuitively `enable_if` is just the identity operator (for types) if the first argument is true. But the compiler has no special knowledge of `enable_if`. This is equivalent to saying: find `T` such that `Foo<T>::type` is `Bar`. The compiler has no way to do this shy of instantiating `Foo` for every single T, which is not possible.

We want to use enable_if, but not in a way that disables deduction. The best way to use `enable_if` is typically in a defaulted template parameter:

```
template<typename T, typename U = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, VectorInt>::value>::type >
void serialize(T& vect) {
  std::cout << vect.x << std::endl;
}
```

`U` isn't used for anything, but when `serialize` is passed a `VectorInt`, it will now deduce `T` from the passed argument, and then it will deduce U which has a default. However, if the enable_if argument is false then U will not correspond to any type, and the instantiation is ill-formed: classic SFINAE.

This answer is already pretty long, but `enable_if` itself is a reasonably deep topic; the form given above works here but doesn't work for disjoint sets of overloads. I'd suggest reading more about ADL, template argument deduction, SFINAE, and enable_if, outside of just SO (blog posts, Cppcon youtube videos, etc).

Comment: This answer was the perfect length, thank you. Your comment about the compiler having no special knowledge of `enable_if` was very helpful, along with the example of finding `T` such that `Foo<T>::type` is `Bar`.